# Just want R to wait for user input before starting execute actions

Tags: r

I created a script where the user is initially asked to enter some inputs that are assigned to variables. However, when you launch the script, R does not wait for the user to enter input to perform operations.  How do I tell R to wait for the user's input before the script starts? Actually my code looks like:

```
fun <- function(){
    x <<- readline("What is the value of x?")  
    y <<- readline("What is the value of y?")
    z <<- readline("What is the value of z?")
}
fun()

#BEGIN OF THE SCRIPT USING X, Y, Z
```

Comment: this piece of code works here. notice you don't know double **<<** ; use *<* instead as shown in the R documentation https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readline.html

Answer (score 2):

Assign the input to variables this way.

```
fun <- function(){
  readline("What is the value of x?") ->> x
  readline("What is the value of y?") ->> y
  readline("What is the value of z?") ->> z
  return (z)
}
```

Now, call your function, but wrap it in an expression if you want to take input from the keyboard...

```
{
fun()
library(httr)
# this is a comment
}
```

Comment: I tried but the problem is the same: the script keeps going on taking script's code as user input :/

Comment: You want to take three numeric values from the keyboard?

Comment: I want user to insert an url, a number and a text: each should be a variable processed by script

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I think the problem was just with the way you were assigning data to your x, y, z variables... Does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is changed. You can see it launching fun() and library(random_package) together

Comment: Finally, I see your problem. I think that just wrapping your script in an expression `{...}` should work fine... If you are patient, you can place everything inside nested functions...